# ItemDeleting Event Receiver Fires Workflow - How Does Item Get Deleted

Tags: workflow

i have a custom Visual Studio document workflow which runs on a single document library in the site collection. I also have an ItemDeleting event receiver to be invoked when someone attempts to delete a document. The event receiver successfully fires the workflow, but the document isn't deleted even after the docuemnt workflow status is approved. I've been trying to figure out how to do this but it has become a delima for me. I tried to delete the document in the event receiver, but it appears to kick of the event receiver again (which is not unexpected). But even if I delete the document in the event receiver, I would need to be able to check the workflow status, i.e. approved, rejected. If I delete the document in the workflow, I would need to know if the document is being deleted.

Any help?

Comment: If you already have an Event Receiver, why don't you write all your workflow login within the Event receiver?

Comment: I built a VS workflow for the document library earlier, to cover documents added and updated. The client then came back and said he wanted the workflow triggered when someone attempts to delete the item. So I'm just trying to figure out if it's possible to use the same workflow via an event receiver. At any rate, I still don't know how the document ever gets deleted.